# Tree of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree such that for all edges $e\in E(T)$, both the components of $T-e$ have odd order. Prove that all the vertices of $T$ have odd degree.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $v$ be any vertex of $T$, let $d=\deg v$, and let $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ be the edges incident at $v$. For $k=1,\ldots,d$ let $T_d$ be the component of $T-e_k$ that does not contain $v$. Suppose that for $k=1,\ldots,d$, $T_k$ has $n_k$ vertices, and $T$ has $n$ vertices.

- Is $n$ odd or even?
- $\sum_{k=1}^dn_k=n-1$; why?
- What does this tell you about the parity of $d$?